# I accidentally did "git remote rm heroku" , after I had Multiples remote gits ...Now ALL remotes disappeared

Tags: git, heroku, cmd

I've had a problem with the error "Multiple remote heroku apps" , so I looked it up in the
web , one of the answers was "git remote rm heroku" , I did it , now I have no remotes at all . When I look in the Heroku dashboard , my URI is there , I don't know what commands I should run in the cmd to fix this ...Please Help!

I've looked around the web , but no useful answers :(

Comment: Add the `heroku` remote: `git remote add heroku <heroku-repo-url>`

Comment: ..... and then do `git fetch heroku` and it should be back.

Comment: Thanks, it still made me problems , so i've deleted the entire thing and started from the beginning. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Add back the remote with:

```
$ git remote add heroku <heroku-url>
```

Some documentation suggests a remote named `heroku`, which can be a problem if the application is deployed to multiple Heroku instances (staging, production, etc.). To avoid this problem in the future, add each remote with a unique name:

```
$ git remote add heroku-staging <heroku-staging-url>
```

Or, if you find yourself in this situation again, rename existing `heroku` remotes instead of removing them:

```
$ git remote rename heroku heroku-staging
```